# Counting the number of records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails application, I have the following DB schema:
each User has many Members and each Member has many Tags.
The link between the tables is direct (Members table has a user_id column and Tags has a member_id column).

What is the most **efficient** way to count the number of Tags associated with the user?
Is it through Rails and activerecord or pure sql?

Any thoughts/examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Tag model you can add a scope:

scope :count_by_user, lambda { |user|
    members.where("members.user_id >= ?", user)
  }

How about that? Do you have the members function/relationship in your Tag model?

Comment: I got `undefined method 'tags' for #<User:0xb544630>` since in the user module there isn't a direct link to the Tags model (and I dont wish to change it)

Comment: fixed the call..how about now?

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
User.first.tags.count
```

(This is assuming you have a relationship set up in the user model.)

is nearly the same speed(minus the speed of Active Record). AR will be smart enough to LIMIT the results the 1, and actually use the COUNT() sql function, which the the best way to calculate the number of records.

If you were truly worried about these micro-optimizations, than yes, I'm sure you can shave a ms or two if you write pure SQL and bypass AR.

Comment: This call will count the number of tags associated with User.first.